# Binding spinner with two related attributes

Tags: android, data-binding, android-spinner

I want to bind the android spinner in way that I can bind primary key with the attribute.
For example, I've a table of city in database, which has two columns "cityID" and "cityname". Now, how could  I bind both in spinner. So, when one select the city in spinner, I get the id of that city. 
It is similar to combo box Value Member and Display Member in C#.NET

Comment: and did you had a question ?

Comment: please help me, if anyone can give right solution/answer

Comment: I'm using String list for spinner items `List<String> lables;` And now I want to add and get two strings from each list item `lables.add("This is android");`. And then bind to spinner Adapter. And I want like `lables.add("id","This is android");`  so when click on any Item, I get both id and cityName in back-end codes.

Comment: create objects that encapsulate all the values you'd need, and then use a list of those objects as your data source in the adapter. On selection, just retrieve the index of the selected object and do what you gotta do with it

Answer (score 0):

may be this will helps you ;) :)

http://rimpv.blogspot.in/2013/05/bind-spinner-dropdown-in-android.html